# XMLHttpRequestで、「readyState === 4」かつ「ステータスコードが200以上300未満」ではない 状態を意図的に作り出したい

Tags: javascript, ajax

**XMLHttpRequestで、readyState === 4 となる、HTTPステータスコードを教えてください**
・403エラーや、404エラーは、ここで弾かれるでしょうか？

**また、「readyState === 4」　かつ 「HTTPステータスコードが200以上300未満」ではない 条件だと、何が該当するでしょうか？**
・可能性があるHTTPステータスコードは？
・(テストしてみたいので、)この状態を意図的に作り出すことは出来るでしょうか？

---

↓ 追記しました。
・下記コードで、何のために条件分岐をしているのか分からなかったので質問しました。
・elseのところでalert表示させるよう、試しにサーバ側を404エラーにしたのですが、うまくいきませんでした(別の箇所でエラーが出てしまったので)

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
        } else {
            alert("test"); //ここをalert表示させたい
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***XMLHttpRequestで、readyState === 4 となる、HTTPステータスコードを教えてください**

・403エラーや、404エラーは、ここで弾かれるでしょうか？*

[XMLHttpRequest(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)
[W3Cの最新ドキュメント](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#states)
[HTTPプロトコル(RFC)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4)
「弾かれる」と言う表現で何を期待しているのかわかりませんが、readyStateの4:DONEはすべてのデータ転送が完了した状態を意味します。HTTPステータスコードを送ってきているということはデータ転送をしているわけですから、**すべてのHTTPステータスコード**に対してreadyStateは全レスポンスの受信を完了した時点で4になります。(ただしredirect系のレスポンスはXMLHttpRequestが自動的に処理してしまうので、3xxのステータスコードが受信されることはないと思います。)

***また、「readyState === 4」　かつ 「HTTPステータスコードが200以上300未満」ではない 条件だと、何が該当するでしょうか？**

・可能性があるHTTPステータスコードは？

・(テストしてみたいので、)この状態を意図的に作り出すことは出来るでしょうか？*

上に書いたように3xx系以外のすべてのステータスコードで可能性があります。404:Not Foundの場合でもレスポンスの受信が完了した時点でreadyStateは4になるので、存在しないpathに対してGETメッセージを送るだけで簡単に試せます。

この辺りのXMLHttpRequestの挙動を調べることで、実際は何に応用したいのでしょうか、もう少し上のレベルで本当は何をしたいのか、を質問された方が、より有用な回答が得られるように思いますが。

Comment: 質問背景を本文に追記しました。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。あなたのコードを付け足してみて試しましたが、404コードを返すような存在しないpathを指定したところ普通に"test"と書いたalertが表示されます。XMLHttpRequestの使い方が他の部分で誤まっているのか、「サーバ側を404エラーにした」方法が悪いのかご記載の内容だけでは判定できません。事象を再現するために十分なコード(xhrにインスタンスを代入する部分から実際にリクエストの送信を開始する部分まで全て)を記載していただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 色々な所を経由して最終的にどうやらXMLHttpRequestを使用しているらしい、ということしか把握できていないので、稼動部分のコードを掲載することが出来ません。質問した時点ではもしかしたら404コードは「readyStateが4:DONE」にならないのではないかと疑っていたので、その部分に関して原因の切り分けは出来ました